# How can I detect when the mouse cursor is over a button?

Tags: unity, c#

Not clicked event but over the button event ?
I want that when the mouse cursor is on the button call a function.

[image: On Click event is working but the but the Pointer Enter is not working.]

When I click on the button it's calling the function playing a sound.
I tried to add a Pointer Enter event calling the same function but it's not playing the sound when the mouse cursor is above the button.

This is the function :

```
public void MouseClick(string buttonType)
    {
        if (buttonType == "Controls")
        {
            transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            controlsMenu.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 6;
        }

        if (buttonType == "Graphics")
        {
            transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            mainMenuCanvases.SetActive(false);
            GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(false);
            graphicsMenu.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 3;
        }

        if (buttonType == "Sound")
        {
            transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            mainMenuCanvases.SetActive(false);
            GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(false);
            soundMenu.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 4;
        }

        if (buttonType == "Exit")
        {
            transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            Debug.Log("YES QUIT!");
            Application.Quit();
        }

        if (buttonType == "Options")
        {
            newGameClicked = true;

            transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(false);
            GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 2;
        }

        if (buttonType == "NewGame")
        {
            newGameClicked = true;
            transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            mainMenuCanvases.SetActive(false);
            menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(false);
            newGameDialog.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 7;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the way you called `MouseClick` in the inspector you passed the "NewGame". In the pointer event you didn't pass anything. Your MouseClick function plays a sound only if one of those if conditions has been matched. With an empty string no if condition will match and nothing will happen.

If you want the same sound to play as it does on click, you should write in the inspector something like "NewGamePointerEnter", and in the on click function add a new if expression that will match and play the sound, with the same line you wrote before.

```
if (buttonType == "NewGamePointerEnter")
{
    transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the string you wrote for pointer enter is not matching an if that does the functionalities of a click?